# How to run files in a batch, 5 files at a time, from a folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, directory

I have a folder of about 100 files. I would like to run 5 files at a time. For first 5 files, I want to run a function, `my_func` and then I want to run for the next 5 (6..10) files etc..

What `my_func` does is combining files together. So, I want to combine first 5 files write them to a directory and then go to next 5 files.

This is what I did so far,

```
file_list = os.listdir(read_path)
len(file_list)

for file in range(len(file_list)):
    if file <= 4:
        my_func()
    ## Not sure How to go to Next Five after runing my_func
```

Any help on completing this code would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built in `range` with a step to get the index of every 5 files, and then slice the list accordingly.

```
num_files_per = 5

for file_index in range(0, len(file_list), num_files_per):
    file_batch = file_list[file_index : (file_index+num_files_per)] # Slice a batch of 5 files
    my_func(file_batch) # Run your function on batch of 5 files
```

The 3rd argument in `range` will determine the step size, which is 1 by default.

Comment: thanks for quick response. My function already takes in an argument. What can I for this. When I use a `for` loop like you had earlier, it runs forever

Comment: I would have to see your `my_func` to be sure how to pass the files to it, could you post the code for that? I am confused about how you want to pass in the batch of files. The `file_batch` variable holds a set of 5 file objects at a time that you can iterate through in any way you would like.

Comment: my function takes in tow parameter, 1: folderpath, 2: file write path. I think I'll try to take from here. Thank you again!